# Primality Test in Finite Fields

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, finite-fields, primality-test

Is there a name for the following primality test? Was it ever discussed in literature?

We want to test if some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is a prime number.

Let $p = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k +1$ some [primorial prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime) such that $p_k < x < p_{k+1}^2$. And let $g$ be some generator of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. We can test if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is prime:

\begin{equation}
    \prod_{i=1}^k (g^{\frac{p-1}{p_i} \cdot x} - 1)^{p-1} \bmod p =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if}\ x \text{ is prime} \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
  \end{equation}

This product implements the [trial devision algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

---

Furthermore, is there a name for the resulting prime counting function? For all integers $n$ such that $p_k < n < p_{k+1}^2$ the number of primes up to $n$ is:
\begin{equation}
    \pi(n) = k + \sum_{x=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^k (g^{\frac{p-1}{p_i} \cdot x} - 1)^{p-1} \bmod p     
\end{equation}

---

Generalization 1: $p$ does not have to be a primorial prime. A prime of the form $p = m \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k +1$ with some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is sufficient.

---

Generalization 2: $p$ can even be a composite. It's sufficient if $\varphi(p)$ is divisible by $2,3,5,7,11,\ldots,p_k$.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no finite field $\Bbb{F}_p$ because $p$ need not be prime. Already for $k=6$ you have
$$p=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13+1=59\times509.$$

Comment: $p$ does not have to be a primorial prime. Any prime of the form $p = m \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k +1$ with some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is sufficient. So, for $k=6$ you could use e.g. $p = 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 + 1$

Answer (score 0):

So for a given $x$ you choose $p_k$ such that $p_k < x < p_{k+1}^2$ and construct $p = 2\cdot 3 \cdots \cdot p_{k}+1$. But $p$ may not be prime, so you need to test if $p$ is prime. So your algorithm for primality test include testing if a (much bigger) number is prime?

Comment: Yes. I am not claiming that this algorithm is computationally efficient.

Comment: The point is that $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains the exact structure of all primes from $p_k$ to $p_{k+1}^2$.

Comment: This is sometimes used as an implementation trick to compress trial division by multiple small primes (but usually not all of them, as you are doing here). But it is so impractical that I don't think it worths a name.

Comment: @LinusK And my answer i meant to make this clear: this wouldn't be considered an algorithm since it wouldn't finish.

Comment: @jjagmath Still, this formula is helpful to reason about primes.
E.g. it tells you that every prime mod 30 is a prime or 1

Comment: @jjagmath, just realized $p$ does not even have to be prime. It's sufficient if $\varphi(p)$ is divisible by $2,3,5,7,11,\ldots, p_k$.